# Is it possible to execute the indicator signal a couple of seconds before the candle closes?

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading

analysis of trading strategies in a pine tree, if there is a signal, occurs only after the candle closes. This is an invariable condition when evaluating a pine test. Tell me, if there are any additions to the code so that the indicator fulfills the condition a couple of seconds before the close of that candle? the task is to combat slippage

Comment: Nope, it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can only do this in realtime, as Pine scripts run on the bar's close on historical bars. Code like this would work to trigger an alert only in the last x% of the bar. Note that you need the barstate.isconfirmed failsafe to catch cases where the script doesn't execute in the last x% of the bar, in which case it the alert will trigger on the bar's close.

```
//@version=4
study("")
pct = input(99.)
f_chartTimeInterval() => var _timeDelta = 10e15, _timeDelta := min(time - nz(time[1]), _timeDelta)
pctBarElapsed = 100 * (timenow - time) / f_chartTimeInterval()
cond = barstate.isconfirmed or pctBarElapsed > pct
plotchar(pctBarElapsed, "pctBarElapsed", "", location.top, size = size.tiny)
```